# How to reload/refresh a Google Maps tile layer?

Tags: google-maps

I've got a tile layer that I want to remove and replace with another one in Google Maps.  My tile layer is defined in MapOptions using GetTileUrl to call a function.

For instance, I want to be able to remove a county layer and replace it with a census tract one.

When I try to do this it only loads the new layer when I pan the map.  I think I need to remove the old tiles from Google's cache (as if I turn browser caching turned off this still happens).

I've tried the map "resize" event, but it doesn't work.

Do I need to set the map to null and reinitialize everything?  Or can I just reload my map tile layer?

When I change the layer, the URL for the tile loading changes - so I'm guessing that adding a fake parameter won't help me.

The code is pretty long (and has extra stuff in it), but if you want to see this in action you can go to [JusticeMap.org](http://www.justicemap.org)

```
var jmapMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(jmapTypeOptions);
map.overlayMapTypes.push(jmapMapType);
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed to store the jmapMapType in a global variable.

Then I can remove it, and add it back.  This reloads the tiles:

```
map.overlayMapTypes.removeAt(0);
map.overlayMapTypes.push(jmapMapType);
```