# Catching errors loading google maps tiles

Tags: javascript, google-maps

We have a google maps api application, and our users sometimes experience flaky network connectivity. The result of this is generally that they'll get a blank map because the tiles won't load when the map is told to go to some place. If you watch the javascript console, you can see errors get output for the tiles not loading. I'm trying to catch those errors in the hope I can make the map try to reload the tiles after a bit of time. However, it seems there is no functionality built into google maps to throw an event for this error. Also, they appear to load the tiles via the src of an IMG element. It's pretty easy to handle errors on my own IMGs, but I can't think of a way to tie into there's.

Is this basically an impossible task, or is there some sort of way into it? This doesn't actually have to be a google maps-specific question, but solutions like using jQuery's ajax error handling, setting up error handlers on my own IMG tags, etc. won't work.

Also, if it helps, our users only use Chrome. Chromium Embedded Framework build 3.2171.2069, to be specific. I think if I was able to use a newer version of CEF (there are very annoying roadblocks there), I might be able to tie into some new CEF resource events. But I can't, so that's not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: can u post your error logs? i think you need to force reloading your map tiles. You can visit this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841015/how-to-reload-refresh-a-google-maps-tile-layer)

Comment: I've never actually had any error logs, per se, as I've never been able to figure out how to trap the error (hence my question). And just to clarify, this is using the default map tile layer, not a custom one. I'm beginning to wonder if my best bet isn't just to set a dead man's switch based on the tilesloaded event. If it doesn't get a tilesloaded event within X seconds, reload the page.

Comment: And now I realize tilesloaded won't do any good without a good way to know that tiles NEEDED to load. Because when panning around and such, it doesn't always need to load tiles.